# Regex \b word boundary not works

Tags: java, android, regex

In Android I have the next regexp `\b(id)\b`,

In this query (i.e.) I want replace exactly the word 'id' :

```
SELECT schedules.id as 'idreal' FROM schedules WHERE schedules.id = 12;
```

Final query:

```
SELECT schedules._id as 'idreal' FROM schedules WHERE schedules._id = 12;
```

But it doesn't work, the \b is for word boundary, but it doesn't work. What i'm doing groing?

This is my code:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\b(id)\b").matcher(field);
String query = matcher.replaceAll("_id");

Log.v(TAG, "Clean Query: "  + query);
```

I tested in

Thanks a lot.

Comment: answered by falstru. You need to escape the backslash one more time

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should escape `\` to represent `\` literally. Otherwise `\b` means a backspace characters.

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\b(id)\\b").matcher(field);
```